# Scrapu-Splash returns 502 or 504 status

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy-splash

My problem is that I get 502 or 504 status. But this is not always the case. Sometimes the spider can work normally, as it should work. But sometimes some queries return 502 or 504. However, these are always random requests. It also sometimes happens that the spider first returned the 502 or 504 status for a certain page, but later, scrappy informs me that this page was successfully collected and saved(this variation is presented in the log). How can this be? And how do I get rid of these problems?

```
import os
import re
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from .utils.config import HTML_DIR


class CqSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "cq"    

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-ucs-director-xss-O7T8ORYR',
            'https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-code-exec-wH3BNFb',
            'https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-dcnm-stored-xss-yJyqBJGU',
            'https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-20190807-wms-oredirect',
            'https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-20190501-asaftd-saml-vpn',
        ]

        for url in urls:

            yield SplashRequest(
                url=url,
                callback=self.save_response,
                endpoint='render.html',
                cb_kwargs=dict(path_dir=HTML_DIR),
                args={
                    'wait': 1.0,
                    'timeout': 90.0,
                },
            )


    def save_response(self, response, path_dir, filename=None):
        if not filename:
            filename = self.norm_url(response.url)
        print('===')
        print(filename)
        print('===')
        with open(path_dir / filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'splash'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['splash.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'splash.spiders'
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 2
SPLASH_URL = 'http://172.35.0.1:8050'

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy_user_agents.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
}

SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
}

DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
```

log:

```
docker-compose -f $(pwd)/tor/docker-compose.yml up -d
        Creating network "tor_tor_net" with driver "bridge"
        Creating tor ... done
        docker-compose -f $(pwd)/splash/docker-compose.yml up -d
        Creating network "splash_splash_net" with driver "bridge"
        Creating splash ... done
        docker run --rm --env-file .secrets --env-file .settings \
            --name cisco-crawler \
            -e DATA_DIR=/data \
            -v $(pwd)/data/crawlers/cisco:/data \
            -v $(pwd)/crawlers:/code \
            docker-secdev.ptsecurity.ru/crawler-base:fixed_cisco_crawler \
            cisco
        2020-08-18 15:51:01 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.3.0 started (bot: splash)
        2020-08-18 15:51:01 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.2.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.7.8 (default, Aug  5 2020, 08:30:24) - [GCC 8.3.0], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020), cryptography 3.0, Platform Linux-5.4.0-42-generic-x86_64-with-debian-10.5
        2020-08-18 15:51:01 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor
        2020-08-18 15:51:01 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
        {'BOT_NAME': 'splash',
         'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 2,
         'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter',
         'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'splash.spiders',
         'SPIDER_MODULES': ['splash.spiders']}
        2020-08-18 15:51:01 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: a2db66b61d0f2c0d
        2020-08-18 15:51:01 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
        ['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
         'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
         'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
         'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
        2020-08-18 15:51:03 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedBrowserType] Family: Android
        2020-08-18 15:51:03 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: Other, Brand: None, Model: None
        2020-08-18 15:51:03 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: Other, Brand: None, Model: None
        2020-08-18 15:51:04 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: Other, Brand: None, Model: None
        2020-08-18 15:51:04 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: Sony BDV13, Brand: Sony, Model: BDV13
        2020-08-18 15:51:04 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: Nintendo DSi, Brand: Nintendo, Model: DSi
        2020-08-18 15:51:04 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: Other, Brand: None, Model: None
        2020-08-18 15:51:04 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedBrowserType] Family: Other
        2020-08-18 15:51:04 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: LYF F90M, Brand: LYF, Model: F90M
        2020-08-18 15:51:05 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: Sony BDV14, Brand: Sony, Model: BDV14
        2020-08-18 15:51:05 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: LG Web0S SmartTV, Brand: LG, Model: Web0S SmartTV
        2020-08-18 15:51:05 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: Other, Brand: None, Model: None
        2020-08-18 15:51:06 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: Other, Brand: None, Model: None
        2020-08-18 15:51:06 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: Other, Brand: None, Model: None
        2020-08-18 15:51:06 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: Other, Brand: None, Model: None
        2020-08-18 15:51:06 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: Other, Brand: None, Model: None
        2020-08-18 15:51:06 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: Other, Brand: None, Model: None
        2020-08-18 15:51:06 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: Other, Brand: None, Model: None
        2020-08-18 15:51:06 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: Sony BDV11, Brand: Sony, Model: BDV11
        2020-08-18 15:51:06 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: Other, Brand: None, Model: None
        2020-08-18 15:51:06 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: Other, Brand: None, Model: None
        2020-08-18 15:51:06 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: Other, Brand: None, Model: None
        2020-08-18 15:51:06 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: Other, Brand: None, Model: None
        2020-08-18 15:51:07 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: Nintendo DSi, Brand: Nintendo, Model: DSi
        2020-08-18 15:51:07 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: LYF LF-2403N, Brand: LYF, Model: LF-2403N
        2020-08-18 15:51:07 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: LYF F90M, Brand: LYF, Model: F90M
        2020-08-18 15:51:07 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: Other, Brand: None, Model: None
        2020-08-18 15:51:08 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: Other, Brand: None, Model: None
        2020-08-18 15:51:08 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedBrowserType] Family: Applebot
        2020-08-18 15:51:08 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: Other, Brand: None, Model: None
        2020-08-18 15:51:08 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedBrowserType] Family: Applebot
        2020-08-18 15:51:09 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedBrowserType] Family: Other
        2020-08-18 15:51:09 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedBrowserType] Family: Other
        2020-08-18 15:51:09 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedBrowserType] Family: PhantomJS
        2020-08-18 15:51:09 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedBrowserType] Family: SMTBot
        2020-08-18 15:51:10 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedBrowserType] Family: PhantomJS
        2020-08-18 15:51:10 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedBrowserType] Family: PhantomJS
        2020-08-18 15:51:10 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedBrowserType] Family: WebKit Nightly
        2020-08-18 15:51:10 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedBrowserType] Family: PhantomJS
        2020-08-18 15:51:10 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: Other, Brand: None, Model: None
        2020-08-18 15:51:11 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedBrowserType] Family: PhantomJS
        2020-08-18 15:51:11 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedBrowserType] Family: PhantomJS
        2020-08-18 15:51:11 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedBrowserType] Family: Robot
        2020-08-18 15:51:11 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: Other, Brand: None, Model: None
        2020-08-18 15:51:11 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedBrowserType] Family: Zune
        2020-08-18 15:51:11 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
        ['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
         'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
         'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
         'scrapy_user_agents.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware',
         'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
         'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
         'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
         'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
         'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware',
         'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware',
         'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
         'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
         'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
        2020-08-18 15:51:11 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
        ['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
         'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware',
         'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
         'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
         'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
         'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
        2020-08-18 15:51:11 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
        []
        2020-08-18 15:51:11 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
        2020-08-18 15:51:11 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
        2020-08-18 15:51:11 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
        2020-08-18 15:51:11 [py.warnings] WARNING: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy_splash/request.py:41: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function to_native_str. Use to_unicode instead.
          url = to_native_str(url)
        
        2020-08-18 15:51:11 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36
        2020-08-18 15:51:11 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
        2020-08-18 15:51:11 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.62 Safari/537.36
        2020-08-18 15:51:11 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36
        2020-08-18 15:51:11 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36
        2020-08-18 15:51:11 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
        2020-08-18 15:51:11 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36
        2020-08-18 15:51:11 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36
        2020-08-18 15:51:11 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
        2020-08-18 15:51:11 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.89 Safari/537.36
        2020-08-18 15:51:31 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-ucs-director-xss-O7T8ORYR via http://172.35.0.1:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times): 502 Bad Gateway
        2020-08-18 15:51:31 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
        2020-08-18 15:51:31 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-dcnm-stored-xss-yJyqBJGU via http://172.35.0.1:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times): 502 Bad Gateway
        2020-08-18 15:51:31 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
        2020-08-18 15:51:38 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-code-exec-wH3BNFb via http://172.35.0.1:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times): 502 Bad Gateway
        2020-08-18 15:51:38 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
        2020-08-18 15:51:41 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-dcnm-stored-xss-yJyqBJGU via http://172.35.0.1:8050/render.html> (failed 2 times): 502 Bad Gateway
        2020-08-18 15:51:41 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36
        2020-08-18 15:51:46 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-code-exec-wH3BNFb via http://172.35.0.1:8050/render.html> (failed 2 times): 502 Bad Gateway
        2020-08-18 15:51:46 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36
        2020-08-18 15:52:06 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-ucs-director-xss-O7T8ORYR via http://172.35.0.1:8050/render.html> (failed 2 times): 502 Bad Gateway
        2020-08-18 15:52:06 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.170 Safari/537.36
        2020-08-18 15:52:06 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-20190807-wms-oredirect via http://172.35.0.1:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times): 502 Bad Gateway
        2020-08-18 15:52:06 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36
        2020-08-18 15:52:11 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
        2020-08-18 15:52:51 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-20190501-asaftd-saml-vpn via http://172.35.0.1:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times): 504 Gateway Time-out
        2020-08-18 15:52:51 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
        2020-08-18 15:52:59 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] ERROR: Gave up retrying <GET https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-code-exec-wH3BNFb via http://172.35.0.1:8050/render.html> (failed 3 times): 502 Bad Gateway
        2020-08-18 15:52:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (502) <GET https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-code-exec-wH3BNFb via http://172.35.0.1:8050/render.html> (referer: None)
        2020-08-18 15:52:59 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <502 https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-code-exec-wH3BNFb>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
        2020-08-18 15:53:11 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] ERROR: Gave up retrying <GET https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-dcnm-stored-xss-yJyqBJGU via http://172.35.0.1:8050/render.html> (failed 3 times): 504 Gateway Time-out
        2020-08-18 15:53:11 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (504) <GET https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-dcnm-stored-xss-yJyqBJGU via http://172.35.0.1:8050/render.html> (referer: None)
        2020-08-18 15:53:11 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <504 https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-dcnm-stored-xss-yJyqBJGU>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
        2020-08-18 15:53:11 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 2 pages (at 2 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
        2020-08-18 15:53:25 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] ERROR: Gave up retrying <GET https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-ucs-director-xss-O7T8ORYR via http://172.35.0.1:8050/render.html> (failed 3 times): 502 Bad Gateway
        2020-08-18 15:53:25 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (502) <GET https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-ucs-director-xss-O7T8ORYR via http://172.35.0.1:8050/render.html> (referer: None)
        2020-08-18 15:53:25 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <502 https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-ucs-director-xss-O7T8ORYR>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
        2020-08-18 15:53:39 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-20190807-wms-oredirect via http://172.35.0.1:8050/render.html> (failed 2 times): 504 Gateway Time-out
        2020-08-18 15:53:39 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36
        2020-08-18 15:54:11 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 3 pages (at 1 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
        2020-08-18 15:54:21 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-20190501-asaftd-saml-vpn via http://172.35.0.1:8050/render.html> (failed 2 times): 504 Gateway Time-out
        2020-08-18 15:54:21 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.89 Safari/537.36
        2020-08-18 15:55:03 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-20190501-asaftd-saml-vpn via http://172.35.0.1:8050/render.html> (referer: None)
        ===
        tools.cisco.com-security-center-content-CiscoSecurityAdvisory-cisco-sa-20190501-asaftd-saml-vpn
        ===
        2020-08-18 15:55:05 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-20190807-wms-oredirect via http://172.35.0.1:8050/render.html> (referer: None)
        ===
        tools.cisco.com-security-center-content-CiscoSecurityAdvisory-cisco-sa-20190807-wms-oredirect
        ===
        2020-08-18 15:55:05 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
        2020-08-18 15:55:05 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
        {'downloader/request_bytes': 12060,
         'downloader/request_count': 15,
         'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 15,
         'downloader/response_bytes': 454960,
         'downloader/response_count': 15,
         'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
         'downloader/response_status_count/502': 9,
         'downloader/response_status_count/504': 4,
         'elapsed_time_seconds': 233.602478,
         'finish_reason': 'finished',
         'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 18, 15, 55, 5, 265746),
         'httperror/response_ignored_count': 3,
         'httperror/response_ignored_status_count/502': 2,
         'httperror/response_ignored_status_count/504': 1,
         'log_count/DEBUG': 35,
         'log_count/ERROR': 3,
         'log_count/INFO': 16,
         'log_count/WARNING': 46,
         'memusage/max': 59252736,
         'memusage/startup': 58208256,
         'response_received_count': 5,
         'retry/count': 10,
         'retry/max_reached': 3,
         'retry/reason_count/502 Bad Gateway': 7,
         'retry/reason_count/504 Gateway Time-out': 3,
         'scheduler/dequeued': 20,
         'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 20,
         'scheduler/enqueued': 20,
         'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 20,
         'splash/render.html/request_count': 5,
         'splash/render.html/response_count/200': 2,
         'splash/render.html/response_count/502': 9,
         'splash/render.html/response_count/504': 4,
         'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 18, 15, 51, 11, 663268)}
        2020-08-18 15:55:05 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
        docker-compose -f $(pwd)/splash/docker-compose.yml down
        Stopping splash ... done
        Removing splash ... done
        Removing network splash_splash_net
        docker-compose -f $(pwd)/tor/docker-compose.yml down
        Stopping tor ... done
        Removing tor ... done
        Removing network tor_tor_net`
```

Comment: getting the same error, did you figure it out?